# Handling of SI prefix in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of tables in a SQL Server database that track electronic components.

As such, I have resistors with a 'value' between 0 and 10M, and capacitors with a 'value' between 1p and 1u.

I would like to perform simple math on these values, but must account for the SI prefixes first.

Any suggestions for how this can be done purely within SQL? Most related questions seem to use python, etc. to do the work external to the database. This is not an option in my case.

EDIT: Request for further information

I have the 'value' field populated by Engineers, and thus they are stored as varchar, in formats such as 3n3, 2.2k, 1M, etc. There may be a decimal point, or the SI prefix acts as the decimal point.
The primary purpose of this data is for displaying on schematics, hence the ugly human-readable format.
My question is specifically about how to interpret the human-readable values into scientific notation (or unity scale), so that their numerical interpretation can be used for calculations inside the SQL server.

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: Just give each table an implicit SI unit.

Comment: Just to clarify: are the SI prefixes part of the value e.g. "1u" or stored in a separate column. I am trying to understand if your question is about parsing values?

Comment: @Mureinik, sorry, I didn't supply any data as I didn't think it was pertinent to the question. I wasn't looking for a complete working answer, just suggestion on how to handle converting SI units to numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am thinking this will be the most straightforward option.

Comment: @Alex, you are correct. The prefixes are stored with the values, as a varchar. The question relates to removing the prefix, and applying its scaling factor to the remaining number such that the result is a numerical format that can then be calculated with.

Answer (score 2):

Your case really needs a better description.

But starting from the basics, you need to choose 1 unit as a base unit for the database. (ok, so 1 unit for resistors, 1 unit for capacitors)
Store all your values in that base unit.
Store the 'outside world' unit is a separate column.

Now that all your values are in the same unit, you can perform calcualtions on them.
When it is time to output to the outside world, use a lookup table to convert to whatever units are required.

Thus :

```
    create table test.resistors(
    name nvarchar(1000)
    ,value int
    ,unit smallint
)
insert into test.resistors([name],[value],[unit])
values('2 milliOhms resistor',2,1)
insert into test.resistors([name],[value],[unit])
values('2000 Ohm resistor',2,3)
insert into test.resistors([Name],[value],[unit])
values('10 Meg resistor',10,4)


create table test.resistorUnits(
    code smallint identity(1,1)
    ,name nvarchar(60)
    ,Ohms float
)
insert into test.resistorUnits([name],[Ohms])
values('m',.0001)
insert into test.resistorUnits([name],[Ohms])
values('Ohms',1)
insert into test.resistorUnits([name],[Ohms])
values('k',1000)
insert into test.resistorUnits([name],[Ohms])
values('M',1000000)

select 
    R.name,  R.value * U.Ohms as [Value in Ohms], cast(R.value as nvarchar) + ' ' + U.name as [Original Value]
from test.resistors R inner join test.resistorUnits U
        on R.unit = U.code
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, this takes the prefix off; it is possible you will want to multiply these with each other, in which case you'll need the 'big number' represented by the number multiplied by the number represented by the prefix. If so let me know, as that is doable. If you intend to do maths with each number singly, I assume this will be satisfactory.

```
CREATE TABLE Component_Values
(
ID INT IDENTITY(11,1),
[value] nvarchar(11)
)
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('815.048u')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('90.3m')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('3659.88105d')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('260.976da')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES (651.8098)
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('88.917Y')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('54.8673p')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('75.256G')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('121.9183T')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('88.657y')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('0.001Z')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('86E')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('8878.99P')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('2.3758z')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('9899.22a')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('4578.999f')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('766n')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('8.021c')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('7644.0984h')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('8787.223k')
INSERT INTO Component_Values VALUES ('7M')

CREATE TABLE #Number
(
ID INT,
[Number] Float
)
INSERT INTO #Number
SELECT
ID, 
CASE WHEN RIGHT([value],2) NOT LIKE '[a-z][a-z]' AND RIGHT([value],1)
                           NOT LIKE '[0-9]' 
                           THEN (left([value],len([value])-1))
     WHEN RIGHT([value],2) LIKE '[a-z][a-z]' 
                           THEN (left([value],len([value])-2))
     ELSE [VALUE]
 END
 FROM Component_Values

 SELECT * FROM #Number
```

Comment: I think that the above, whilst may need adjusting to the specifics of your case, pretty much illustrates your path forward.